# Handle multiple dispatch in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I would like some help with calling multiple dispatch. I have the below code but the dispatch calls are asynchronous. I am not sure how to make synchronous dispatch calls? Below is my code.

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.props.getItem1()
    this.props.getItem2()
    this.props.getItem3()
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item1Fetching: state.item1.fetching,
  item1Error: state.item1.error,
  item2Fetching: state.item2.fetching,
  item2Error: state.item2.error,
  item3Fetching: state.item3.fetching,
  item3Error: state.item3.error,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getItem1: () => {
    dispatch(Item1Actions.item1Request())
  },
  getItem2: () => {
    dispatch(Item2Actions.item2Request())
  },
  getItem3: () => {
    dispatch(Item3Actions.item3Request())
  },
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoadingScreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

as a workaround you can create a single action to dispatch and in execution of that action you can dispatch your three item fetching methods one by one.

in your `mapDispatchToProps` method you can do the following

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(itemsAction, dispatch)`

in your actions.js
you can do the following....

```
`export const itemsActions = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return item1Request().then((data) => {
      dispatch(data);
      return item2Request().then(data2 => {
        dispatch(data2);
        return item3Request().then(data3 => dispatch(data3))
      })
    })
  }
}`
```

I hope this helps you.
this way you can make them one by one

Comment: Is this the only way? I would like to split it across multiple redux rather than putting everything in the same.